# Changing variable based on window size - jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Having issues with this. So in short I want var hprH = 555px when screens are >= 910px, then hprH = 300px when screens are between 910px - 400px and 150px when < 400px.  I tried this with CSS media queries, but couldn't get it to work.  So now I am trying to do this solely in js.

This is the **global** variable

```
var hprH = $('#hpr').height();
```

I would like to change this as stated above.

Here is the code that uses the variable, which works until I need the hprH height to be less than 555px.

```
$(function() {
    hpr_init();

    $('#hpr .thumb').click(function(){
            clearInterval(timer);
            showHPR($(this));
    });
            timer = setInterval(function(){showHPR(nextThumb);}, interval);
    $(window).resize(function(){
            hprH = $('#hpr').height();
            $('.selected').height(hprH);
    });
});
function showHPR(obj){
    $(obj).fadeOut(300,function(){  
            $(obj).parent().animate({ 
                    height:hprH,
                    zIndex:0,
                    bottom:0
            },duration);

            $(obj).parent().find('img').animate({ 
                            top:0
                    },500,function(){
                            $(this).css({bottom:'auto'});
                    });
            $(obj).parent().find('.content').fadeIn(); 
            lastThumb(obj); 
     });        
}
```

Comment: Could you add a jsFiddle for us to play with your code? Need to see the HTML you're using. I'm sure it could still be done in CSS unless you need some logic done... but I need to play with it first.

Comment: @philtune http://jsfiddle.net/md7o859h/

Comment: `$(window).height()` will return height of window. you can start there.

Comment: To note - I did not code this - I cleaned it up a bit, but I inherited this :[

Comment: and wrap in a if statement such as `if($(window).height()>xxx) {do something}`

Comment: Trying to make the #hpr and #hpr div.content 's height basically auto based on width or just program it hard at break points.  I don't need the height of the window - more of the element.

Comment: Also if you resize your browser - you will see the image shrink, but not the containing element.  I want them both to stay in sync.  Tried media queries, but the js is interfering.

Comment: Can you provide the media queries that you used in your attempt?